# Find all quadratic residues modulo $15$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Find all quadratic residues modulo $15$.

I'm having trouble understanding how my professor got the solutions.

I know that the quadratic residue is $x^2 \equiv q \bmod p.$

The answers she got was $1,4,6,9,10.$

Since

$1^2 \equiv 1 (\bmod15)$

$4^2 \equiv 1 (\bmod15)$

$6^2 \equiv 2 (\bmod15)$

$9^2 \equiv 6 (\bmod15)$

$10^2 \equiv 10 (\bmod15)$

I'm trying to grasp on how she got the answers, and why $
5^2$ or $7^2$ won't work?

Edit: Thank you for the quick responses, I understand now how they got the quadratic residues, it ended up being easier after seeing the answers Thank you!

Comment: $5^2=25=10$ does work modulo $15$. Also $7^2=49=4$ modulo $15$.

Comment: Can you explain please?

Comment: What do you want to know?

Comment: Hmm, nevermind, i think i'm starting to get what you are saying, let me look at the other people's responses just to make sure i'm not getting confused.

Comment: Just test yourself, whether or not $4$ is a quadratic residue modulo $15$. Take a look again at the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ if there exists $x\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x^2\equiv a\bmod p$ has a solution.

So, working in modulo $15$; we have $$1^2=1,\quad 2^2=4,\quad 3^2=9,\quad4^2=1,\quad 5^2=10,\quad6^2=6,\quad7^2=4,$$ $$8^2=4,\quad 9^2=6,\quad 10^2=10,\quad 11^2=1,\quad 12^2=9,\quad 13^2=4,\quad14^2=1.$$

So the quadratic residues modulo $15$ are $\{1,4,9,10,6\}.$

Comment: so essentially we are looking at the outcomes from the squared values from 1 through 14.

Comment: Indeed. As an exercise; do the same for modulo $17.$

Comment: Sure thing! I'll work on it right now Thanks! ( I'll post what I got as soon as I finish.

Comment: No worries. I look forward to seeing your answer.

Comment: I got $\{1,2,4,8,9,13,15, 16\}$ and when i was computing I realized that there was a pattern where they were repeating from the begging and starting to the end backwards. Ex. $ 1^2 =1$ and $ 16^2=1$ so forth.

Comment: That is correct and that's very nice that you spotted such a pattern. In order to see why; observe $16=-1\bmod 17$ so squaring $16$ gives you $1$ which is the same as $1^2$ as you mention. It is for this reason we get this [result](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_Quadratic_Residues_of_Prime)

Comment: It's my pleasure!

Comment: But shouldn't 0 also be in the quadratic residues modulo 15?. I think you should have done $0^2 = 0 mod 15$. Or no? After all, its the set of integers.

Comment: @Joker you're certainly correct - zero is seen as a trivial case and there are some texts that exclude or include $0$ to always be a quadratic residue.

Answer (score 1):

You have the definition a bit backward. $1^2 \equiv 1,$ so $1$ is a quadratic residue, $2^2 \equiv 4,$ so $4$ is a quadratic residue, and so on. The quadratic residues are the things which are themselves squares mod $p;$ you shouldn't attempt to square them.